# next.js and three.js model(gltf model) loading two time

Tags: reactjs, three.js, next.js, 3d-model

**I am using Chakra-UI with next-js**
I only want to load the model one time.
I go through all code many times but I did not find the error in the code. so anyone can help me to find out the error in the code. and why this happening.

### index.js file:

```
import { Container } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import PavanLogo from "../components/PavanLogo";
import PavanLogoLoader from "../components/PavanLogoLoader";

const LazyPavanLogo = dynamic(() => import("../components/PavanLogo"), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => <PavanLogoLoader />,
});

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <LazyPavanLogo />
    </>
  );
}
```

### PavanLogo.js file:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
import { loadGLTFModel } from "../lib/model";
import { PavanSpinner, PavanContainer } from "./PavanLogoLoader";

function easeOutCirc(x) {
  return Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(x - 1, 4));
}

const PavanLogo = () => {
  const refContainer = useRef();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [renderer, setRenderer] = useState();
  const [_camera, setCamera] = useState();
  const [target] = useState(new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 1.2, 0));
  const [initialCameraPosition] = useState(
    new THREE.Vector3(
      20 * Math.sin(0.2 * Math.PI),
      10,
      20 * Math.cos(0.2 * Math.PI)
    )
  );
  const [scene] = useState(new THREE.Scene());
  const [_controls, setControls] = useState();

  const handleWindowResize = useCallback(() => {
    const { current: container } = refContainer;
    if (container && renderer) {
      const scW = container.clientWidth;
      const scH = container.clientHeight;

      renderer.setSize(scW, scH);
    }
  }, [renderer]);

  /* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
  useEffect(() => {
    const { current: container } = refContainer;
    if (container && !renderer) {
      const scW = container.clientWidth;
      const scH = container.clientHeight;

      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true,
        alpha: true,
      });
      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      renderer.setSize(scW, scH);
      renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
      container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
      setRenderer(renderer);

      // 640 -> 240
      // 8   -> 6
      const scale = scH * 0.005 + 4.8;
      const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
        -scale,
        scale,
        scale,
        -scale,
        0.01,
        50000
      );
      camera.position.copy(initialCameraPosition);
      camera.lookAt(target);
      setCamera(camera);

      const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xcccccc, 1);
      scene.add(ambientLight);

      const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
      controls.autoRotate = true;
      controls.target = target;
      setControls(controls);

      loadGLTFModel(scene, "/Model/pavan.gltf", {
        receiveShadow: false,
        castShadow: false,
      }).then(() => {
        animate();
        setLoading(false);
      });
      let req = null;
      let frame = 0;
      const animate = () => {
        req = requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        frame = frame <= 100 ? frame + 1 : frame;

        if (frame <= 100) {
          const p = initialCameraPosition;
          const rotSpeed = -easeOutCirc(frame / 120) * Math.PI * 20;

          camera.position.y = 10;
          camera.position.x =
            p.x * Math.cos(rotSpeed) + p.z * Math.sin(rotSpeed);
          camera.position.z =
            p.z * Math.cos(rotSpeed) - p.x * Math.sin(rotSpeed);
          camera.lookAt(target);
        } else {
          controls.update();
        }

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      };

      return () => {
        console.log("unmount");
        cancelAnimationFrame(req);
        renderer.dispose();
      };
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize, false);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleWindowResize, false);
    };
  }, [renderer, handleWindowResize]);

  return (
    <PavanContainer ref={refContainer}>
      {loading && <PavanSpinner />}
    </PavanContainer>
  );
};

export default PavanLogo;
```

### PavanLogoLoader.js file:

```
import { forwardRef } from "react";
import { Box, Spinner } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export const PavanSpinner = () => (
  <Spinner
    size="xl"
    position="absolute"
    left="50%"
    top="50%"
    ml="calc(0px - var(--spinner-size) / 2)"
    mt="calc(0px - var(--spinner-size))"
  />
);

export const PavanContainer = forwardRef(({ children }, ref) => (
  <Box
    ref={ref}
    className="pavan"
    m="auto"
    mt={["-20px", "-60px", "-120px"]}
    mb={["-40px", "-140px", "-200px"]}
    w={[280, 480, 640]}
    h={[280, 480, 640]}
    position="relative"
  >
    {children}
  </Box>
));

const Loader = () => {
  return (
    <PavanContainer>
      <PavanSpinner />
    </PavanContainer>
  );
};

export default Loader;
```

### when it runs load two model

[logo loaded twise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoHTZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

React.StrictMode makes useEffect which loads the logo run twice. The solution is to disable it in next.config.js.

```
reactStrictMode: false
```